# Hibernate HHH000346 Error during managed flush. Insert not committed

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, wildfly, jhipster

I created an app using Jhipster (https://www.jhipster.tech/) and all was working fine during development in VSCode. Finally I generated the war file via maven and deployed it into wildfly. At startup the database is created and the app is ready. Then I try to authenticate on the app and here is the issue:

*DEBUG 5220 --- [ default task-1] c.s.t.r.s.RocketUserDetailsService       : Authenticating admin*

*Hibernate: select user0_.id as id1_7_0_, authority2_.name as name1_3_1_ [...]*

*Hibernate: insert into jhi_persistent_audit_event (event_date, event_type, principal) values (?, ?, ?)*

*Hibernate: insert into jhi_persistent_audit_evt_data (event_id, name, value) values (?, ?, ?)*

*WARN  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (default task-1)*

*SQL Error: 1452, SQLState: 23000*

*ERROR [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper] (default task-1) Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`rocket`.`jhi_persistent_audit_evt_data`, CONSTRAINT `fk_evt_pers_audit_evt_data` FOREIGN KEY (`event_id`) REFERENCES `jhi_persistent_audit_event` (`event_id`))*

The full error log is there: https://pastebin.com/FJFL9X6G

What I understand is the second insert does not work because the first one is not persisted so the foreign key points to nothing.

The database is MySQL 5.7 and I am pointed to the same instance with the same account for my tests in VSCode **AND** via the war in Wildfly. So I don't understand why it's not working only with the war package.

Comment: Stack trace shows that you're using Wildfly transaction manager, so it's clearly different from tests or running as an executable war file.

Comment: Thanks Gaël for your answer. I'm completely new to spring, jhipster, wildfly, hibernate... Do you have any resource to help me about how to force use the same transaction manager used by spring please?

Comment: My only recommendation is to run as an executable war unless you are really forced to use WildFly or any app server. Stackoverflow has many questions from JHipster users having various problems deploying into an app server. These questions are mostly unanswered because JHipster community rarely use app servers.